# Return a value that Dynamic SQL Returns

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to write a procedure which calls a SQL inserted in a table. When I execute this procedure it returns a certain value and I need to capture it. Below is an example:

```
Create Proc Temp_TEst 
@ID int
as
BEGIN
Declare @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
   Select @SQL=[sql] from Testtable where ID=1
      /* PRINT @SQL 
         The above select returns the following:

    Select COUNT(*) from TableTest_1 where ID=@ID     
     */
   SET @SQL= REPLACE(@SQL,'@ID',@ID) 
   EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

So if the count returns say 12351 rows . This would give out the result when I execute the procedure like:

```
   EXEC Temp_Test 1;
```

I need to capture the output in a variable inside the Create procedure block and then use the value. Can you please guide me on how I can approach this problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6fd8778c-4fc1-4067-bcb7-724d08af7144/set-the-result-of-execute-into-a-variable-?forum=transactsql) I am afraid you can't use the selected query as is.

Comment: If all of your queries in this table select only a single integer you could do something like this: `DECLARE @t TABLE ( v INT );INSERT @t EXEC (@SQL); SELECT * FROM @t`. Otherwise you will need to expand the temp table to match the return set.

Comment: While not your exact use case, this link may be of some help http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Proc Temp_TEst 
@ID int, 
@OutPut INT OUTPUT
as
BEGIN
Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @OutPut INT;

   Select @SQL=[sql] from Testtable where ID = 1

   SET @SQL=  N' SELECT @OutPut = ( ' + @SQL + N' )'

    Exec sp_executesql @SQL 
                      ,N'@ID INT , @OutPut INT OUTPUT'
                      ,@ID 
                      ,@OutPut OUTPUT
END
```

**Execute Proc**

```
DECLARE @Value INT; 

exec Temp_TEst @ID     = 1
              ,@OutPut = @value OUTPUT   --<-- now this variable will be populated
```